# Making selected input border invisible

Tags: html, css

[image: input normal]

[image: input hover]

[image: input selected]

so for input selected there is a double border appearing but I only want the outer border to show and theres no css I have already thats making the inner border.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    input:focus, textarea:focus, select:focus{
        outline: none;
    }
</style>
```